# Speed of divergence of sequence with converging ratio

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $a_1=1$ for which I know that it diverges, is strictly increasing and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}= a<1$ exists. Additionally the quotient is striclty increasing as well. 
I want to know how $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ behaves asymptotically. I think it grows like $a^n$ but could not prove it yet. Since by strict monotonicity $\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}< a$ I arrived at $a_{n+1}>a^{-(n-1)} a_1 = a^{-(n-1)}$. But this only tells me that it grows faster than $a^n$. How could I fully determine the divergence speed in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $p>0$ and $0<a<1$ let $a_n=n^p\,a^{-n+1}$. The sequence satisfies all the conditions stated in your question, and grows strictly faster that $a^{-n+1}$. Moreover, this growth id different for different values of $p$. So, in general, you cannot determine the exact growth. Assuming $a>0$, you can show that for every $\epsilon\in(0,a)$ there is an $n_\epsilon$ such that if $n\ge n_\epsilon$, then $a_n\le(a-\epsilon)^{-n+1}$.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Very helpful but unfortunate... Is there maybe a book or other ressource on the analysis of divergent sequences?

Comment: There is Divergent series by G.H. Hardy, but it studies series, not sequences. By the way, you van shot that $\log(1/a_n)/n$ converges to $\log(1/a)$.